# writing low values at the start of a Python list

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a little Python program that is supposed to iterate through a list of lists. If the first value of any of the sub-lists is lower than the first value of the first sub-list in the new list, the program should prepend this sub-list. If not, the program should append the sublist.

```
myList = [[4, [49, 43, 41]], [3, [51, 52]], [2, [62, 69, 67]], [10, [71, 75]], [0, [4, 8, 7]], [9, [89, 88, 80]]]

newList = []
for item in myList:
    if len(newList) == 0:
        newList.append(myList[0])
    elif item[0] < newList[0]:
        newList.insert(0, item)
    else:
        newList.append(item)
print newList
```

The output of this code is [[9, [89, 88, 80]], [0, [4, 8, 7]], [10, [71, 75]], [2, [62, 69, 67]], [3, [51, 52]], [4, [49, 43, 41]]] whereas it should be [[0, [4, 8, 7]], [2, [62, 69, 67]], [3, [51, 52]], [4, [49, 43, 41]], [10, [71, 75]], [9, [89, 88, 80]]] or something like that.

I can't figure out where the error lies. Does anyone know how to fix this program? (Of course, I realize list.sort() would have a similar effect, but this code is intended to be used in a context where the larger list is too large to be stored in memory and a true ordering is unnecessary in any case.)

Comment: prepending to a large list is not efficient. Use a `collections.deque` instead

Answer (score 1):

Well apart from the fact that this is the most bizarre "sorting" algorithm I've ever seen... (you only sort with respect to whatever list happens to be in the first element of `newList` which means that you end up with `[9, [...]]` located at the end. It would make sense to me for it to be before the entry with `[10, [...]]` in it, but that isn't what you've asked for so I'm ignoring it!)

The problem is that you aren't comparing to the first element of the first element of `newList`.

The line that reads `elif item[0] < newList[0]:` should read `elif item[0] < newList[0][0]:`